# eBay HTML and CSS are not showing borders

Tags: html, css, border

I have created this template for an eBay listing. When I open it in any browser I can see the borders perfectly. However when I paste the code into eBays HTML description and preview it, I see nothing. If I add text and images into the code they will show within the confines of the borders but the border will still be invisible.

Any ideas?

```css
#pdcontainer {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #000000;
}

.holder {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1100px;
}

.body {
  border: 5px solid #66CCFF;
  float: left;
  width: 780px;
  height: 2700px;
  border-right-width: 2px;
}

.sidebar {
  border: 5px solid #66CCFF;
  float: left;
  width: 215px;
  height: 2700px;
  border-left-width: 3px;
}

.header {
  border: 5px solid #66CCFF;
  float: left;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 132px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<div id="pdcontainer">

  <head>
  </head>
  <html>

  <body>
    <div class="header">
    </div>
    <div class="holder">
      <div class="body">
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

  </html>
  </body>
```

Comment: Why do you have a `<div>` before your `<head>` .. that may the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try change names of divs - if ebay use same name, it can replace your CSS.